# SSD suddenley stopped working, displaying it to be 32kb in size

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hardware-failure, controller

One morning my laptop froze so I forcefully shut it down. Afterwards I was no longer able to boot into my operating system. 
Now when I run fdisk -l on a live distribution it shows up as:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 32 KiB, 32768 bytes, 64 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

**is there any way to recover the data from the ssd?**

it is a 256gb ssd, testdisk shows this info:

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 32 KB / 32 KiB - SandForce{200026BB}
```

hardware pic:
[ssd hard drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk8wS.jpg)

Comment: I had a SanDisk CZ80 with exactly the same issues. It's said to be recoverable with a Mass Production tool, bot **not for data**.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's **no** chance for data recovery. However you can still fix the drive and continue to use it.

To recover the drive, you need a firmware update tool for SandForce SF-2281 and a firmware. After the recovery the drive is usable.

There's no way to recover the LPA table on the SSD, so no one can know how the data on it is arranged. Thus data on the drive is hardlt recoverable.